# storing image path in mysql and the image inside a folder

Tags: php, mysql

It always echo "image path saved"  but nothing gets saved

I've also tested the connection and it connecting normally

I've searched and the only results that I get is using "mysql_connect" which soon will be removed

//I do not get errors in this code

```
  //submiting form
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
     //connecting ot db
     $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '',       '');

            //naming and saving into a folder
            $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
            $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
            $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
            $filepath = "article_images/".$filename;


            // insert path into db -but nothing gets done
            move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
            $query = "INSERT INTO 'Article' ('img_name','img_path','img_type') VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
            if($query)
            {
                echo "image path saved";
            } else {
                echo "nothing saved";
            }enter code here



        }

?> enter code here
```

the form works fine but can't see what is wrong

Comment: where you executing the query ?

Comment: You aren't executing your query

Comment: And you definitely do _not_ want to use the client side provided filename for internal usage. You cannot trust _any_ data you received from the client side. Generate an internal file name instead that is based on the session id, the user id and a timestamp.

Comment: thank you. but I'm just trying to get the images uploaded and saved and after I would look in make it secure.

Answer (score 1):

Execute your **insert query**

So, your code will be like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'Article' ('img_name','img_path','img_type') VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')");
```

Note: Hash Image name before inserting it to database.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Use code like this.

  <?php
  $DBhost = "localhost";
  $DBuser = "";
  $DBpass = "";
  $DBname = "";

  $DBcon = new MySQLi($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBname);


  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {   

        //naming and saving into a folder
        $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
        $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
        $filename = time()."_".$filename;
        $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
        $filepath = "article_images/".$filename;


        // insert path into db -but nothing gets done
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

        $query = $DBcon->query("INSERT INTO 'Article' ('img_name','img_path','img_type') VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')");

        if($query)
        {
            echo "image path saved";
        } else {
            echo "nothing saved";
        }enter code here



    }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **enctype** in your form? If not you need to use this in the form tag and try again..

```
<form action="filename.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Hope it helps...